# instal rVol in tradingview

Tags: tradingview-api

I would like to install volume (relative volume (volume intraday divided by average volume of the last 3 months)), I've already found the script, but I haven't figured out how to create the parameter for this so that the values ​​are always 3 months / stand intraday. can someone please tell me where to put this?

https://www.tradingview.com/script/n0f50JKv-Relative-Volume-at-Time/